# calculate login time for an employee in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have been trying to calculate total login time for employees in my map reduce program using java. My reducer wasn't giving me any output, hence I tried to output the key value pairs as it is. I am unable to organize my arraylist in reducer based on date to perform total time calculation.
Your help on this is much appreciated.

My log file contains employees login details as given below.

```
101 IN 9:00
102 IN 9:15
103 IN 9:16
104 IN 9:25
103 OUT 10:00
105 IN 10:30
101 OUT 11:30
101 IN 11:45
102 OUT 12:30
101 OUT 13:00
105 OUT 13:05
104 OUT 14:30
```

My map function is a given below

```
public class login_map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>{
public void map (LongWritable key,Text value,OutputCollector <Text,Text>output, Reporter reporter)throws IOException{
String line = value.toString();
String emp_id = line.substring(0, 3);
String punch = line.substring(4);
output.collect(new Text (emp_id), new Text(punch));
}
}
```

The corresponding reducer is as given below

```
public class login_reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>{ 
    public void reduce(Text key,Iterator <Text> values,OutputCollector <Text,Text>output,Reporter reporter)throws IOException{
        ArrayList<Date> a = new ArrayList<Date>();
        SimpleDateFormat punch = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        while (values.hasNext()){
            String entry = values.next().toString();
                try{a.add(punch.parse(entry.substring(7)));}
            catch(java.text.ParseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       //end of while
        Iterator itr = a.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()){
            output.collect(key, new Text(itr.next().toString()));
        }
}
}
```

Expected output

```
101 3:45
102 3:15
103 0:44
104 4:55
105 2:35
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting `101 3:45`?? That value is not in the input data, and you aren't even attempting to calculate differences in time in your code.

Comment: I tried to calculate the time and as unable to fetch output from reducer, hence I modified my code to output the data from the list directly. Apparently that also does not seem to be working

Comment: Have you looked at the data the reducer is actually getting? `entry.substring(7)` is out of bounds

Comment: In other words, you are looping over `["IN 9:00", "OUT 10:30", "IN 11:45", "OUT 13:00"]`... I don't think you need Hadoop to write an algorithm to just *test the expected output* on that list. What you should really be doing is writing unit tests with your expected inputs and outputs, then move the code into Mapreduce form

Comment: Also, btw. One flaw in this data is that what if you had someone clock in-out "overnight". You have no concept of which day you are working with from this file

Comment: Change the Reducer to buffer all values. Then sort the values based on time. Finally, iterated on the sorted values to calculate total login time.